# Delete X-Requested-With when use RestangularConfigurer?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I tried to use the RestangularConfigurer for configuring my restangular, but I have no idea for replacing this:

```
 delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

into RestangularConfigurer like this:

```
RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHeaders({
        'useXDomain': true,
        'someHeader' : 'blabla',
        //this will delete the X-Requested-With Headers... 
        ??? 'X-Requested-With' : ????
    });
```

Anyone have solutions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete stuff with Restangular setDefaultHeaders, but Restangular uses $http below, so keeping the line `delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];` will work as well with Restangular :)

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, maybe you can support that in the future? It's nice to have all the settings in one place :)